# Can you identify this engine?

Tags: jet-engine, engine, turbojet

I am studying Aircraft mechanics currently, and in our academy we have some aircraft engines and different types of them, and I need please your help to know the reference of one of them, and if it is possible the engine manual of it, because it is essential for us to study it deeply.

[image: Engine Label]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It appears to be a [Rolls Royce Viper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_Siddeley_Viper) turbo jet engine made in 1966. The maker's mark (BSB) derives from [Bristol Siddeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Siddeley), formed from [Armstrong Siddeley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_Siddeley) (the company that originally developed the engine) and [Bristol Aero-engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bristol_Aeroplane_Company). Bristol Siddeley were later taken over by [Rolls Royce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Limited).

[image]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong_Siddeley_Viper)</sup>